# Qt3D input handling system works differently depending on the place it was created

Tags: c++, qt, qt3d

I was implementing a custom camera controller for `Qt3DRender::QCamera` and I faced a rather strange behavior of the `Qt3DInput::QMouseHandler`. Depending on the environment it was created it either responds to mouse events or not. There are two cases: create both the device and the handler in the `MainWindow` object or create them inside my camera controller class (it only works in the first case).

**First case:**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    auto* window = new Qt3DExtras::Qt3DWindow();

    auto* window_container = QWidget::createWindowContainer(window, this, Qt::Widget);
    setCentralWidget(window_container);

    auto* scene = new Qt3DCore::QEntity();
    window->setRootEntity(scene);

    auto* mouse_device = new Qt3DInput::QMouseDevice(scene);
    auto* mouse_handler = new Qt3DInput::QMouseHandler(scene);
    mouse_handler->setSourceDevice(mouse_device);

    connect(mouse_handler, &Qt3DInput::QMouseHandler::positionChanged,
        [](Qt3DInput::QMouseEvent* event)
        {
            qDebug() << "I am actually printing to console!!!";
        });
}
```

**Second case:**

```
class CustomCameraController final : public Qt3DCore::QNode
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit CustomCameraController(Qt3DCore::QNode* parent = nullptr)
      : Qt3DCore::QNode(parent),
        mouse_device(new Qt3DInput::QMouseDevice(this)),
        mouse_handler(new Qt3DInput::QMouseHandler(this))
    {
        mouse_handler->setSourceDevice(mouse_device);

        connect(mouse_handler, &Qt3DInput::QMouseHandler::pressAndHold, this,
          &CustomCameraController::MousePositionChanged);
    }

public slots:
    void MousePositionChanged(Qt3DInput::QMouseEvent* event)
    {
        qDebug() << "I am not printing anything...";
    }

protected:
    Qt3DInput::QMouseDevice* mouse_device;
    Qt3DInput::QMouseHandler* mouse_handler;
};


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    auto* window = new Qt3DExtras::Qt3DWindow();

    auto* window_container = QWidget::createWindowContainer(window, this, Qt::Widget);
    setCentralWidget(window_container);

    auto* scene = new Qt3DCore::QEntity();
    window->setRootEntity(scene);

    auto* controller = new CustomCameraController(scene);
}
```

*All the unnecessary code was removed. The `main.cpp` file was automatically generated by Qt Framework*

I searched all through the Qt documentation and found nothing that would help me in this scenario. I also noticed that if the device and the handler are initialized in the constructor with `parent` as the parameter it does not help. Furthermore, I tried to create the device and the handler in the MainWindow scope and pass them to the controller via some setter function but it does not help neither.

**So the questions I want to ask: what is the proper way of using `Qt3DInput::QMouseDevice` and `Qt3DInput::QMouseHandler`? Is there a better workaround for implementing input handling for my custom camera controller?**

### Update 1:

*You should add the controller class declaration to the header instead of main window source file. Here are all the includes and the qmake options you are going to need:*

```
#include <Qt3DCore/QNode>
#include <Qt3DInput/QMouseDevice>
#include <Qt3DInput/QMouseHandler>
#include <Qt3DExtras/Qt3DWindow>
#include <Qt3DCore/QEntity>
```

`3dinput 3dcore 3dextras`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you just connected to different signals.
In first case you are using `&Qt3DInput::QMouseHandler::positionChanged` which will be sended quite often. In second one - `&Qt3DInput::QMouseHandler::pressAndHold` which will be sended when a mouse button is pressed and held down.
After fix both logging functions are called.

Comment: I just noticed that and it actually worked. I am so confused. I am investigating into the problem I faced later, it definitely did not work in some case. I will post an update if I find the problem

Comment: Classical debug session for 10 hours because of a simple mistake. Thank you, @jdfa, the question is closed :)